# Simplifying multiple boolean checks into a single one

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, dry

In one of our tests, we have the following set of expectations:

```
expect(headerPage.dashboard.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
expect(headerPage.queue.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
expect(headerPage.claimSearch.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
expect(headerPage.claim.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
expect(headerPage.case.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
expect(headerPage.calendar.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

On one hand, having multiple simple expectations provide a more precise and understandable feedback, but, on another, this looks like it *violates the DRY principle* and the *"one expectation per test"* commonly acceptable guideline.

Is there a way to convert/simplify it to a single expect?

---

<sup>`headerPage` is a Page Object, `dashboard` and other page object fields are navigation links.</sup>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the purpose of the "one expectation per test" guideline.  The point isn't to combine a bunch of expectations into a single expectation, it's to split up your expectations into separate tests.

To follow the spirit of that guideline, you would write your tests like this:

```
describe("The header page", function () {
    var headerPage;
    beforeEach(function () {
        //Common logic here
    });

    it("displays the dashboard", function () {
        expect(headerPage.dashboard.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });

    it("displays the queue", function () {
        expect(headerPage.queue.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });

    it("displays the claimSearch", function () {
        expect(headerPage.claimSearch.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });

    //etc.
});
```

That's a fair bit more verbose than what you have; but that's why these are guidelines not rules.  It's a tradeoff between how verbose you make your tests, versus how easy they are to debug later.  ("The header page displays the dashboard: FAILED") is a very clear and specific test failure message, compared to getting the same failure message regardless of which expectation actually failed.

I definitely would not try to combine all of these lines into a single line.  If you don't want to split it into a bunch of different test cases I would just leave it how it is.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I also think about approaching it differently - to have a page object method that would return current visible navigation links and assert it instead. Will also post here when ready. Thanks so much!

Comment: FYI, posted what I've ended up with.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach. What I've ended up with was to add a page object method that returns the *labels of the currently visible navigation links*:

```
this.getVisibleLinks = function () {
    return $$(".ap-header-nav-tabs li a").filter(function (link) {
        return link.isDisplayed();
    }).getText();
};
```

Then, the above test would be transformed to a concise and readable:

```
expect(headerPage.getVisibleLinks()).toEqual(["Dashboard", "Queue", "Claim Search", ...]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is logic you are using across multiple specs, you could look into jasmine [custom matchers](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html) to encapsulate the logic.

It would be written somewhat like this:

```
var customMatchers = {
    toDisplayWidgets: function(util, customEqualityTests) {
        return {
            compare: function(actual, expected) {
                  function isDisplayingWidgets(page) {
                      return page.dashboard.isDisplayed() && 
                             page.queue.isDisplayed() &&
                             page.claimSearch.isDisplayed() && 
                             page.claim.isDisplayed() &&
                             page.case.isDisplayed() && 
                             page.calendar.isDisplayed();
                  }

                  var result = {};
                  result.pass = isDisplayingWidgets(actual);

                  if (!result.pass) {
                      result.message = 'dashboard is not displayed';
                  }

                  return result;
          }
    }
}
```

Add the matcher to your current test

```
jasmine.addMatchers(customMatchers);
```

And then in your tests you could just assert with

```
expect(headerPage).toDisplayWidgets();
```

Answer (score -1):

what about using a helper function that returns results of all the tests, something like

```
expect(headerDisplayTests()).toBe(true);

function headerDisplayTests() {
    return headerPage.dashboard.isDisplayed() && 
            headerPage.queue.isDisplayed() &&
            headerPage.claimSearch.isDisplayed() && 
            headerPage.claim.isDisplayed() &&
            headerPage.case.isDisplayed() && 
            headerPage.calendar.isDisplayed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about the "Extract the method" trick, but this would not work as is since `isDisplayed()` returns a promise..`protractor.promise.all()` would be needed here. Please see if you can adjust the answer to take that into account.

Comment: if isDisplay() returns a promise, then how would your example of expect(headerPage.dashboard.isDisplayed()).toBe(true); ever work?

Comment: Yes, because protractor has the expect patched to implicitly resolve the promises..

Comment: If such an expectation fails, You'll have a hard time finding out which part of it is broken.